# How do I find a word within range of another word with regex?

Tags: java, regex

if I have a string
"word3 word2 **word3** word4 **word5** **word3** word7 word8 word9 word10"

And I want to find all "word3" such that it is within 3 words of "word5",
I would get a match to the second and third occurrences of "word3"

what regex expression or logic would I use? I had 2 ways I was going to approach it, but they seem incredibly inefficient to me.

Comment: Start by spliting the part within 3 words of `word5` (ie `word2 word3 word4 word5 word3 word7 word8`) then apply a regex to this part

Comment: What are those `two ways` ?

Comment: @looser, (1) find the occurrence of word5 and then use the index to get a substring that i can search and (2) find all occurrences of word3 and see if there is a word5 near it

Comment: @webNeat, how would i go about finding the start index for the 3 words behind word5 in order to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define a *word*, hence I will take this as a word character sequence, and here is an approach without exclusively using regexes, by iterating through splitting the `String`:

```
String str = "word3 word2 word3 word4 word5 word3 word7 word8 word9 word10";
String[] words = str.split("\\W+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // Iterate in an inner loop for nearby elements if "word5" is found.
    if (words[i].equals("word5"))
        for (int j = Math.max(0, i - 3); j < Math.min(words.length, i + 3); j++)
            if (words[j].equals("word3")) {
                // Do something with words[j] to show that you know it exists.
                // Or use it right here instead of assigning this debug value.
                words[j] = "foo";
            }
}
// Prints the result.
for (final String word : words)
    System.out.println(word);
```

> [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/2BpfQG) STDOUT:
>
> ```
> word3
> word2
> foo
> word4
> word5
> foo
> word7
> word8
> word9
> word10
> ```

Otherwise, here's the regex replacement:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("word3(?=(?:\\W*\\w++){0,2}?\\W*+word5)|(word5(?:\\W*\\w++){0,2}?\\W*+)word3");
Matcher matcher;
String str = "word3 word2 word3 word4 word5 word3 word7 word8 word9 word10";
while ((matcher = pattern.matcher(str)).find())
    // Do something with matcher.group(1) to show that you know it exists.
    // Or use it right here instead of replacing with this empty value.
    str = matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1) == null ? "" : matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(str);
```

However while this regex works, replacing away the third word `word3` deemed the first word `word3` able to be replaced away, which is why regex is not the way to go for this.

> [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/Gi07LX) STDOUT:
>
> ```
>  word2  word4 word5  word7 word8 word9 word10
> ```

Small modification to make this work would be:

```
str = matcher.replaceFirst((matcher.group(1) == null ? "" : matcher.group(1)) + "baz");
```

Comment: I was thinking of going the first way, but my only concern was that the text I'm parsing is thousands of words long. Is there anyway to speed up the process while still running the program using one computer (so no map-reduce or anything like that).

Comment: @user I don't believe using regex can be faster than coding the logic here.